# Does Linq Select does not work with IList?

Tags: linq, select

I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 and it suggested a conversion for a foreach to Linq which then doesn't compile:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<object>();
    list.Add("One");
    list.Add("Two");
    list.Add("Three");

    // To make the point...
    var iList = (IList)list;

    // This doesn't compile and generates CS1061: IList does not contain a definition for Select.
    // I thought Linq gave Select to list types?
    var toStringList = iList.Select(s => s.ToString());

    // The original foreach version:
    var outputList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in iList)
    {
        var itemToString = item.ToString();
        outputList.Add(itemToString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is a set of extension methods on everything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

The non-generic `IList` doesn't implement that interface, so Linq won't work on it.

Visual Studio 2019 Professional with ReSharper doesn't suggest `Select` for me:

[image]

Comment: If I typecast to IEnumerable<object> then I can use Select. In the original this came from, Visual Studio 2019 suggested I use Select with IList, which then doesn't compile

Comment: @imekon: You can always use `iList.Cast<Object>` and use that for your LINQ query, so for example `iList.Cast<Object>().Select(s => s.ToString());`

Comment: Agreed, Cast also casts to IEnumerable<object> which is useful